# Any java APIs to sort list of objects based on passed object's field name?

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons

I have a list of objects and I want to sort by passing the objects' field names and an order (ascending or descending). For example, my object is:

```
class Person{
         private String name;
         private String age;
        //getters and setters
         ..........
}
```

I will pass List `personList`, String `name`, and boolean `isAscending` to an API method for sorting the `personList`. I can implement this by writing an implementation class for Comparator but I want to have a generic method.

That is, if I have `Address` object, I should be able to sort `Address` object list by its field name (for ex: `streetName`).

Basically, I am looking for a generic sort method to sort any kind of list. Any such APIs available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually have getters and setters for the properties you want to use. Using the private fields directly is probably a bad idea anyways.

You can use [BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.7.0/docs/bean-collections/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html) from commons-beanutils. To sort ascending, use `new BeanComparator("name")`, for descending `new BeanCompartor("name", Collections.reverseOrder())`

Answer (score 1):

@Wouter Coekaerts's answer is the simplest way to do this.

**However!**

The problem with any solution that uses reflection under the hood is that reflective operations are significantly more expensive than their non-reflective (compiled code) equivalents.  Typically 1 to 2 *orders of magnitude* more expensive.

In your case, the comparator is going to be called `O(NlogN)` times each time you sort the object list.  If your application is going to be sorting large lists ... or small lists lots of times ... the overheads of using a reflective comparator *could* make a big difference to your application's overall performance.

If performance turns out to be an issue (and profiling tells you that the reflective comparator is at fault), the alternatives are:

- Write the comparators by hand.  This is the simplest and most performant solution, whether or not you think it is elegant.
- Use run-time source code generation to generate comparator classes and then compile and load them.
- Use run-time bytecode generation to generate comparator classes and load them.

These could be combined with a lookup / caching mechanism that stores the comparators in a hash table using a key that combines the class and the field name.  (A cache is essential if you use the code generation approach.  But you still need to consider whether any given generated comparator will be used often enough to justify the *large* once-off overhead of generating/compiling/loading a class.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a functional barrier to passing a "string" to identify a field. But if there was a generic way api available it would probably ask you to use a map or to have a get("fieldname") method to get the field it sorts on.

I would use a Comparator instead of Comparable if you are going to change the way you sort.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a [reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

String fieldValue(Object obj, String fieldName) {
     Class c = obj.class;
     Field f = c.getField(fieldName);
     return (String)f.get(obj);
}
```

There may be some leak of typing, but you can always fix it manually by checking field's type with `f.getType()`.